# Nifi:how to handle trnasfer 'transaction' based on flowFile amount in nifi?

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I want to  make transfer  operation when  i   will  have certain amount  of  flowFile  in my  flowFile  queue, and  i make  remove  operation for unused File . Can remove operation   cause  to  dissapear  flowfile from  my  flowfile  array list ?  here is  my  code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import groovy.lang.*

def flowFile=session.get();
def name=flowFile.getAttribute("realName")
def count=flowFile.getAttribute("count")
def  filename=flowFile.getAttribute("filename")
def value= count as Double;
def numb=Math.round(value)
def List<FlowFile> flowFiles= new ArrayList<>();
flowFiles.add(flowFile)

if(flowFiles.size()==numb){
for(FlowFile i in flowFiles){
if(i.getAttribute("filename").substring(0,10)==name){
session.transfer(i,REL_SUCCESS);

}
}
}

else{

session.remove(flowFile);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are waiting for X number of flow files to be received, you can use something like this (assuming you want 10 flow files):

```
def flowfileList = session.get(10)
if(flowfileList.size() < 10) {
  session.rollback()
  return
}
​// If you get here, you have 10 flowfiles in flowfileList
```

Comment: i don't  know   exactly  how  many  flowfile  i need  to  transfer,it  is  based  o this  def count=flowFile.getAttribute("count")  value

Comment: what  do   you  think  this  version  can  be better?

Comment: def flowFile = session.get()
int numb=(flowFile.getAttribute("count") as Double).round()
session.rollback();
def flowFiles = session.get(numb)
if (!flowFiles || flowFiles.size()<numb){
   
    session.rollback()
}else{
   
    
    session.transfer(flowFiles, REL_SUCCESS)
}